# Can I use Type-S mortar and rock to set wood fence posts?

Tags: fence, mortar

I am trying to set a fence post by the house to fix up a gate door. The usual "bag mix" for this job is a mixture of quarter inch stone and cement and lime. However, I also have a bag of type S mortar that I haven't used and would like to use or be rid of. Would it be compromised or ineffective to use some stone and type S mortar to set the fence? or is there too much sand and lime in the mix?

Answer (score 1):

If that is what you have, Type S will work just fine, the trick is that the fill around the post is preferred to be harder than the dirt that the post and cement is in. If there is any "scrap" bags of cement, or concrete that even has lumps in it, that is a perfect spot to make use of it.